# ¿Cuál de las dos maneras mandar a llamar escenarios en JAVAFX?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder, apache-netbeans

Buen día a todos, me estoy iniciando en JAVAFX, he estado viendo algunos tutoriales de cómo cambiar de ventanas de javafx, encontré algunas diferencias. Encontré formas de hacerlo, pero no sé cuál es el recomendado, quisiera que me orientaran para elegir cuál usar.
Adjunto un pedazo de código,estas son las dos formas que encontré de hacerlo:

Manera #1:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Scene1Controller {
 private Stage stage;
 private Scene scene;
 private Parent root;

public void switchToScene2(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/vista/Scene2.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }  
}
```

Manera #2:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;


public class MenuController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private AnchorPane content;  

@FXML
private void salir(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {        
  Parent menu = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/LoginFXML.fxml"));
  content.getChildren().removeAll();
  content.getChildren().setAll(menu);        
 }
}
```

¿Podrían explicarme al respecto, por favor?

Answer (score 1):

La manera #1 tiene una  mala práctica , no necesita  crear un nuevo objeto `Scene` porque se puede obtener de `getScene` . Es redundante crear un nuevo objeto si ya hay uno en ejecución . Creo que la única necesidad de hacer una nueva escena es cuando hay que habilitar antialiasing y depthbuffer que se ocupan cuando una escena (o subescena) es en 3d .  El código podría ser así :

```
public class Scene1Controller {
 private Stage stage;
 private Scene scene;
 private Parent root;

public void switchToScene2(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/vista/Scene2.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    // obtener scene con método getScene
    scene = stage.getScene();
    // pasar la raiz cargada desde fxml a scene con metodo setRoot
    scene.setRoot(root);
    stage.show();
  }  
}
```

El segundo método es mucho más flexible ya que se puede ocupar tanto para cargar un `Parent` nuevo a la escena , como para cargar cualquier nodo a cualquier otro existente en la escena . Como ejemplo  supongamos que necesita  añadir una figura u otra dependiendo de la acción de un botón . todo esto sin cambian de escena . Algo así :

[image: fxml javafx]

En el mismo código dejo comentarios para explicar que sucede .
note que cada vez que se quiere cambiar todos los hijos de un nodo , se puede usar el método `clear()` antes de añadir el siguiente. Además , para poder usar toda la funcionalidad del objeto , hay que usar casting adecuadamente .

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

    // el nodo que va a contener las figuras cargadas de fxml 
    private StackPane container = new StackPane();
// si está el circulo añadido o no
    private boolean isCircleAdded = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

        Button button = new Button("cambiar figura");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                change();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox(button, container);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    // método para añadir uno u otro nodo 
    private void change() throws IOException {

        if (!isCircleAdded) {
            // elimina todos los nodos hijos 
            container.getChildren().clear();
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("circle.fxml"));
            // casting a clase Circle
            Circle circle = (Circle) fxmlLoader.load();
            // añade a circle como nodo hijo de container 
            container.getChildren().add(circle);
            isCircleAdded = true;

        } else {
            // elimina todos los nodos hijos 
            container.getChildren().clear();
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("square.fxml"));
            // casting a clase Rectangle
            Rectangle square = (Rectangle) fxmlLoader.load();
            // añade square como hijo de container
            container.getChildren().add(square);
            isCircleAdded = false;

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
```

**circle.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.Circle?>


<Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" radius="100.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" />
```

**square.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>


<Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#b55631" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" />
```

Comment: No logro implementar StackPane en mi código.

Comment: el import es `import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;`

Comment: Pero, ¿es lo mismo para las interfaces? es decir, módulos. Porque, en tu ejemplo solamente estás demostrando figuras, y no interfaces como de un login hacia un menu, en mi caso, es de un login para entrar a un sistema de ventas, por eso mi duda.

Answer (score 0):

Te envio estos codigos que permiten la ejecucion para levantar estas ventanas sin problemas.

```
public class ServidorApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(ServidorApplication.class.getResource("Servidor.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
    stage.setTitle("Servidor Leparfum");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
```

}

Y tienes este otro mas elaborado

```
public void desplegarVentanaModal(String nombreVentana) {   
    final Stage ventana = new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        Parent root = this.cargadorFXML(nombreVentana); // archivo FXML que es el Parent que contiene todos los elementos de la vista. fxmlLoader.setLocation(direccionFisica);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setFill(null);
        ventana.getIcons().add(this.imagenLogo());
        ventana.setTitle(nombreVentana);
       

        ventana.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        ventana.setScene(scene);
        ventana.showAndWait();
}
```